# Finding downstream member of tree within SQL Hierarchy Query?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, adjacency-list

I have a binary tree with devices attached to nodes (connected by an adjacency list). I'm trying to compare a device's value to the device downstream of it. I'm having trouble getting the downstream device.

Let's say I have a table:

| DEVICE | NODE | PARENT_NODE | LEVEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | null | 1 |
| null | b | a | 2 |
| null | c | b | 3 |
| 2 | d | c | 4 |
| 3 | e | d | 5 |
| 9 | m | b | 3 |
| null | n | m | 4 |
| 7 | o | n | 5 |

How would I go about joining the closest downstream device to each device row? I'm expecting:

| DEVICE | DOWNSTREAM_DEVICE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 7 | 9 |

Some assumptions: There is no order to the devices or the nodes (assume they're both unique ids). LEVEL is the hierarchy level. I'm using Oracle SQL.

I thought I could just use a lag function to perform this query, but obviously this will not work due to the tree branching. My incorrect results are as follows:

| DEVICE | DOWNSTREAM_DEVICE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 3 <- wrong |
| 7 | 9 |

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT device AS device,
       CASE WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN NULL ELSE device END AS downstream_device
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH device IS NOT NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_node = node
AND        (LEVEL = 2 OR PRIOR device IS NULL)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (DEVICE, NODE, PARENT_NODE, LVL) AS
SELECT 1,    'a', null, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT null, 'b', 'a',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT null, 'c', 'b',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    'd', 'c',  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,    'e', 'd',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9,    'm', 'b',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT null, 'n', 'm',  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,    'o', 'n',  5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DEVICE | DOWNSTREAM_DEVICE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 7 | 9 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aT-mDqLC)